# How to create a correlated update subquery in MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access, correlated-subquery

I'm in the process of normalizing a few tables and I've added a surrogate primary key to a table called `Exams` which holds exam titles.

Previously, the child tables would just use the entire name of the exam as the FK entry.

Now that I've added a autonumbered field to the table, I want to update the entries that use it such as the table where the questions are from as there are over a thousand of them.

Going through each exam with a modified update once I find the name each time would take a while, so I decided to write a correlated subquery in a `UPDATE` query. The query looks like this:

```
UPDATE tblExamQuestion
SET ExamID = (SELECT ExamID FROM tblExam WHERE ExamName = tblExamQuestion.ExamName);
```

Unfortunately, once I write the subquery portion, Access refuses to give me the `Run` option and just displays the *Design View*, *Datasheet View* and *SQL View* for that query. However, it still displays the *Update Query* icon in the object explorer.

Is there a proper way to write this so that Access doesn't get upset?

**Using: Access 2007 with a Access 2003 MDB database.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not:

```
UPDATE tblExamQuestion
INNER JOIN tblExam 
ON tblExam.ExamName = tblExamQuestion.ExamName
SET tblExamQuestion.ExamID = tblExam.ExamID
```

Comment: Yes, it does. You should check your indexes to see if you have set a unique index on ExamID in tblExamQuestion. If that is not the problem, what error message do you get?

Comment: No error message, just the same thing as before -- no `Run` button. Here's a screencap with all the relevant information. http://imgur.com/k1Tly.png See anything missing?

Comment: Click on the Design tab, that is where the run button lives.

Comment: Not design view, the design tab on the ribbon. The view you posted is on the Home tab.

Comment: Oh, brilliant. XD Now I know *another* quirk about Access! Thanks for the help.