# Update largest date, matching two fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBM4p.png)

Hi, I'm looking to update the last column in a blank table.  Picture shows input and desired output.  Trying to pick the largest date where workorder and state match.

I've tried a couple different codes:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mytable.orderstartdate = MAX(table2.earliestdate)
FROM mytable as table2
WHERE (mytable.workorder = table2.workorder AND 
mytable.state = table2.state)
;
```

"Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'MAX(table2.earliestdate) FROM mytable as table2'."

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mytable.orderstartdate = (
SELECT max(earliestdate)
FROM mytable as table2
WHERE (mytable.workorder = table2.workorder AND 
mytable.state = table2.state)
)
;
```

"Operation must use an updateable query"

Edit - click tables link for image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322504/how-to-create-a-correlated-update-subquery-in-ms-access

Answer (score 0):

Write PL/SQL Code.

1. First, select DISTINCT WorkOrder and State and capture in variables.
2. Now, Iterate the list and Write a query to get max date i.e. max(date) using work_order and State in where clause. Capture the
   date.
3. Now, In the same loop write update query setting max(date) and workorder and State in where clause.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT mytable.state, mytable.[Work Order], Max(mytable.Suborderearliestdate)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY mytable.state, mytable.[Work Order];

that returned a table that was correct, showed the max date, but that's where I got stuck.  I tried:
UPDATE mytable
SET mytable.[Work Order] = (
SELECT max(Suborderearlieststartdate)
FROM mytable as table2
WHERE (mytable.[Work Order] = table2.[Work Order] AND mytable.state = table2.state)
)
;
but got "Operation must use updateable query"

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table A
SET A.orderstartDate = (SELECT max(earliestdate) 
                        FROM table B 
                        WHERE A.WorkOrder = B.WorkOrder
                        GROUP BY WorkOrder)
```

not sure if access supports correlated subqueries but if it does...

and if not...

```
UPDATE table A
INNER JOIN (SELECT WorkOrder, max(OrderStartDate) MOSD 
            FROM Table B 
            GROUP BY WorkOrder) C
ON A.WorkOrder = C.workOrder
SET A.OrderStartDate = C.MOSD
```

Answer (score 0):

Check database open mode, it may be locked for editing, or you may have no permission to to file.